# Reload Image without Reloading Page?

Tags: php, html, image, post, reload

I'm doing this as a learning exercise and I'm still a beginner to PHP. I know even less about javascript:

The script that I'm writing should allow a user to upload an image from their hard drive, allow the user to modify it by way of some controls on the page and then display the modified image.

Currently, I'm only using PHP to do this and it requires the user to set the parameters of the controls and then POST them (requiring a complete page reload). Can someone point me in the direction of a better way to do this? Is there anything like this out there that I could take a look at?

It would be great if I could eventually have the image update in real time as a user slides a control. Am I looking for javascript? AJAX?

Here is a basic version of my code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['upload_submit'])) { // PROCESS UPLOAD FORM//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $tmp_file = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'];
                    $filename = basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']);
                    $_SESSION['file_name'] = $filename; // load filename into SESSION so that it survives page reloads from POST
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $filename);
                }

                if(isset($_POST['process_submit'])){ // PROCESS CONTROL FORM//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SESSION['file_name']);
                    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $_POST['colred'], $_POST['colgreen'], $_POST['colblue'], $_POST['colalpha']);
                    imagejpeg($im, "newimage.jpg"); //output to file 
                    imagedestroy($im); // free memory
                    $_SESSION['Modified'] = TRUE; // flag that the image has been modified so that the page will display newimage.jpg instead of original
                }
            ?>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['Modified'])){ // Image has been modified at least once (display modified image. do not display upload form)
                echo("<img src='newimage.jpg' width='400px'><br />");
            }elseif(isset($_FILES['file_upload']['name'])) { // Image has been uploaded but not yet modified (do not display upload form)
                echo("<img src=$filename . ' 'width=400px'><br />");
            } else { // FIRST State that the form is in when the page is loaded. (No image uploaded so display upload form)
                echo("<form action='index.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
                    <input type='file' name='file_upload' />
                    <input type='submit' name='upload_submit' value='Upload' />
                </form>");
            } 

            echo("<form action='index.php' method='post'><br />");  // display form with 4 slider controls (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) and a submit button
                echo("<table>");
                    echo (isset($_POST['colred'])) ? "<tr><td>Red:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colred' min='0' max='255' value=" . $_POST['colred'] . ">255</td></tr>"
                        :"<tr><td>Red:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colred' min='0' max='255'>255</td></tr>";
                    echo (isset($_POST['colgreen'])) ? "<tr><td>Green:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colgreen' min='0' max='255' value=" . $_POST['colgreen'] . ">255</td></tr>"
                        : "<tr><td>Green:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colgreen' min='0' max='255'>255</td></tr>";
                    echo (isset($_POST['colblue'])) ? "<tr><td>Blue:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colblue' min='0' max='255' value=" . $_POST['colblue'] . ">255</td></tr>"
                        : "<tr><td>Blue:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colblue' min='0' max='255'>255</td></tr>";
                    echo (isset($_POST['colalpha'])) ? "<tr><td>Alpha:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colalpha' min='0' max='255' value=" . $_POST['colalpha'] . ">127</td></tr>"
                        : "<tr><td>Alpha:</td><td> 0<input type='range' name='colalpha' min='0' max='255' value='127'>255</td></tr>";
                echo("</table>");
                echo("<button name='process_submit'>Process</button>");
            echo("</form>");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try loading the image with javascript. You can even do preloading!

Comment: PHP will only run once before the page loads in the browser. after that all you can do with php is request a new page (or maybe request a page with ajax). in any case you want to use javascript for in situ page handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do everything you want without all the PHP form controls.
HTML5 added a

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

element which you can put images to and manipulate image data directly with JavaScript. Then you can send that data in the background to PHP to save the image for storage or downloading or whatever.

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/ for some examples of image filters written in javascript. You can also easily crop, rotate, scale, ect using javascript and canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/av01d/FT7a9/

Comment: you dont need a canvas object. you can just perform javascript on an img tag.

Comment: Only for certain basic things. Canvas gives you much greater power of pixel manipulation. That's why it was created. WIth canvas you can draw on image just like its photoshop, which you can't do on an img tag.

Comment: Thanks, user2782001! I'll look into canvas too. That tutorial is doing some very cool stuff. My project is coming from a professor who tasked my with designing a php image manipulation class. His goal is to have me learn php since that's what they use on their in house projects. I'm stuck doing the image manipulation server side but I think handling the updates to the page on the client side is fair game. Canvas is a new one for me: I'll definitely be checking this out later. (I wanted to upvote your comment but I don't have enough rep...)

Comment: Thanks, Octopus. Please see my comment above for why I'm doing this with php. After some reading it looks like what I want to do is use javascript to call my php imagefilter function using the onchange event on the slider as the trigger. After that it looks like I want to reload the image using AJAX. Does this all seem feasible? I'm having a hard time finding examples of anyone else doing this. I usually see that as a sign that I'm using a wrong or peculiar approach.

Comment: After reading some more: it looks like I need AJAX for the whole thing. I'm starting to get a better grip on the relationship (or lack of) between javascript and php. I thought that I could use javascript to trigger a new server request. I clearly need to understand AJAX. Would I be out of line to ask for an example here or a link to something simliar? I really have no idea how much code would be involved in converting this to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Image reloading is not that complicated compared with the uploading process. Forgetting the uploading, you can use javascript to edit the 'src' attribute of an  element to make the image reload.
like:
document.getElementsByTagName("Image1")[0].setAttribute("src", "http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/63/50/59/635059d03e7f3a00219571c767b89c38.jpg");

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to do this in real time? Maybe trigger it from an 'onchange' event from one of the sliders?